# Pound signs (£) disappearing from ASP.NET strings

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, encoding

I'm usually a LAMP developer, but some .NET work has arrived on my plate and I'm a bit stumped.

If I run the following code:

```
<% poundsign = "£" %>
<% Response.Write poundsign %>
<% Response.Write "£" %>
```

… nothing is displayed. However, outside of the <% %> tags (ie in the HTML) £ displays correctly.

I have no trouble displaying the usual alphanumerics, it's just the £ sign that is proving problematic. The underlying file is in Windows 1252 encoding, and I need to serve it as such. If I save the file as UTF-8, I get mojibake instead of a £.

Does anybody have any idea what I can do to make this work, or any settings that might be preventing it from working (other than saving the file in a different format)? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry guys, I should have mentioned earlier, but &pound; won't help. Aside from the fact that my £s aren't appearing on the page, a major part of my problem is that I need to insert strings containing £ into a SQL server database, but if I form a SQL INSERT statement within the ASP, none of the £ signs end up appearing in the database. Inserting £ signs into the database from ASP isn't a problem when I save the .asp files as UTF-8 files, but I need everything to work in Windows 1252 encoding. Thanks again.

Comment: Any reason you're not handling it in the code behind?

Comment: @Sonny Boy, why would that change the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help, everybody. It turns out that the problem was caused by my Windows-1252 ASP file loading a UTF-8 include, thereby messing up the encoding of the resultant page.

Answer (score 5):

Use the ASCII code `&pound;`

It is an HTML entity and needs to be accessed via the code, read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer – alas HTML entities won't help me out, for reasons now explained in my original post. Sorry for not being clearer in the first place!

Comment: Not sure, £ is part of the Windows 1252 encoding character set, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
<% Response.Write("&pound;") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<% poundsign = Chr(163) %>
<% Response.Write poundsign %>
<% Response.Write "£" %>
```

Comment: Oddly enough, chr(163) is displaying as "s".